# Алгоритм Дейкстры на GPU работает медленнее (CUDA)

Tags: c++, cuda

Алгоритм Дейкстры реализован при помощи CUDA, при этом в программе встроен последовательный алгоритм для проверки скорости работы программы. Однако, на GPU программа работает гораздо медленнее, чем на CPU. Связано ли это с передачей данных на видеокарту, бесполезностью программы или есть способ исправить?

Код находится по ссылке ниже:

https://gist.github.com/JlexaSS/7ddc8d946706deb84a2c3c4d73c9bfb7

Скриншоты работы программы:
[image: Работа программы]

Comment: Дейкстра не паралеллится толком. Там всё движение идёт вокруг одного узла с минимальным весом. Потом следующий минимальный и т.д. Или я что-то упускаю?

Comment: @StanislavVolodarskiy, при использовании OpenMP и MPI я делил матрицу на части и находил минимальные значения сначала внутри данных чанков, а затем искал общие минимумы, однако с CUDA знаком слабо и потому скорее всего допустил ошибки, не разделяя данные на части, а лишь создав последовательный алгоритм для вычислений на GPU